# Countable cover of closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\alpha<\beta\in\mathbb{Q}$. I am trying to construct a countable cover of $[\alpha,\beta]\subset\mathbb{R}$ with closed intervals of minimal length centered at rational points.

My question is this: let $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,...\}$ be any enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [\alpha,\beta]$. Let $\{b_n \}\subset (0,1)$ be any monotonically decreasing sequence satisfying
$$b_n\geq \frac{c}{2^{n+1}}\text{ for some }c\in (0,\beta-\alpha).$$
Must it follow that
$$[\alpha,\beta]\subset\bigcup_{n\geq 1}[a_n-b_n,a_n+b_n]\enspace?$$
Note that $b_n\geq \frac{c}{2^{n+1}}$ is a necessary condition, since otherwise taking Lebesgue measure on both sides we get $\beta-\alpha<c<\beta-\alpha$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: It need not follow, we can have lots of overlap. For every strictly decreasing sequence $(b_n)$ and every $N \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find enumerations such that every interval with index $\leqslant N$ is contained in $[a_1 - b_1, a_1 + b_1]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer But what if $(b_n)$ is strictly decreasing but $\lim b_n\neq 0$? For example, if $b_n\rightarrow 1/2\neq 0$.

Comment: If $b_n \geqslant \varepsilon > 0$ for all $n$, then you cover the whole interval, since every real is less than $\varepsilon$ away from a rational.